# How to fix an error in Helper/Data.php

Tags: magento-1.9

Added a couple of functions, trying to call them in the form template and get the error.

```
<?php

    class RonisBT_Feedback_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
    {

        public function getName()
        {
            if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getFeedbackName() != "") {
                $name = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getFeedbackName();
            } else {
                $name = $this->helper('contacts')->getUserName();
            }
            return $name;
        }

        public function getEmail()
        {
            if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getFeedbackEmail() != "") {
                $email = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getFeedbackEmail();
            } else {
                $email = $this->helper('contacts')->getUserName();
            }
            return $email;
        }

        public function getPhone()
        {
            Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getFeedbackPhone();
            $phone = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getFeedbackPhone();
            return $phone;
        }

        public function getMessage()
        {
            Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getFeedbackMessage();
            $message = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getFeedbackMessage();

            return $message;
        }
    }
```

Call

```
<?php echo Mage::helper('feedback')->getName(); ?>
```

I get this error.
Fatal error: Call to undefined method RonisBT_Feedback_Helper_Data::helper()

Comment: Have you declare helper in etc/config.xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are calling `$this->helper('contacts')` from inside your Helper class. The `helper()` function only exists on certain classes, but `Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract` is not one of them. You should instead call `Mage::helper('contacts')`

**Update**

For the sake of a more informative answer, the two core classes that come with the `helper()` function are `Mage_Core_Model_Layout` and `Mage_Core_Block_Abstract`. If you are inside of a class that extends either of these you will be able to use `$this->helper()`. Otherwise you would need to call the global `Mage::helper()`.

Comment: Changed, but the error did not disappear

Comment: Please be sure all cache is cleared/disabled. If you made this change the error message should have changed or gone away. What is the new error message?

Comment: Cache cleared, all the same error

Comment: The compiler reassembled, the error disappeared, but now the function displays nothing (

Comment: Sounds like the error is resolved then, but you have another issue now. At this point I would check each of the pieces in `getName` to make sure they are getting a value. My guess is `$name` isn't getting a value.

Comment: Yes, I found a problem. data did not come, you were right) Thank you very much